# CSS background-image: url(none) leading to errors in apache log file

Tags: html, css, apache

I have run into a strange problem. When I use:

```
background-image: url(none);
```

in my css file, it generates an error in the apache log file:

```
File does not exist: /...../styles/none, referer: http://blabla.com/styles/styles.css
```

I have used the W3C CSS validator and there are no errors (just some warnings about floats needing widths).

I used to have:

```
background-image: none;
```

but I have changed all instances and the most up-to-date stylesheet is used.

Is this normal behaviour or is it more likely that I have an error somewhere in my stylesheet?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is normal.  By using the `url()` syntax, anything you put into the brackets is considered to be a URL.  The browsers are making an http request for a resource called `none`.

Basically, you've specified an invalid url for a background image.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way around it, for example by using background-image:none or is that invalid css?

Comment: "background-image: none" is the best way to go, it's definitely valid css.  Take a look at http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/css/color-background/background.html for more on the various background property elements and the shorthand syntaxes.

Comment: "background-image: none" is a good and correct way of specifying it.